# Count mismatches between rows in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-dates

Need some help on this cause I'm getting an issue

I've this three columns (Time, R1 and R2) and I'm trying to count the mismatches between R1 and R2 but for each month (on the time column)

I already used a formula but I'm having an issue to add 1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPDcGZalx1SyGPjIVDTCYZxc10WYdXZV_p0pHDmu9Vs/edit#gid=0   (the test sheet)

```
=iferror(if(EOMONTH($A64,0)=$A64,SUMPRODUCT(month(Database!$C$2:$C) = month($A64),--(Database!G$2:G <> Database!H$2:H)),""),"Error")
```

This part "month(Database!$C$4:$C) = month($A5)" is where I compare the information of the months, ( but I'm having an issue cause cause "month(Database!$C$4:$C)" only retrieves 4 that is the month of april)

This part "(Database!G$4:G <> Database!H$4:H)" is where I compare the columns R1 and R2

The part "EOMONTH($A5,0)=$A5" is where I take the month to based myself

```
Time R1 R2

2020-04-30  BA  BU

2020-04-30  BU  BA

2020-04-29  BA  BU

2020-04-29  BU  BA

2020-04-28  BA  BU

2020-04-28  AA  BA

2020-04-25  AA  BA

2020-04-22  BU  BA

2020-04-19  AA  BU

2020-04-19  AA  BA

2020-03-27  BA  AA

2020-03-27  BA  AA

2020-03-26  BU  AA

2020-03-18  BA  AA

2020-03-18  AA  BU
```

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Already add the sheet :D

Comment: I am sorry, but I fail to understand the significance of `month(Database!$C$2:$C)`. What is that supposed to be? Please explain. What does that number `5` mean?

Comment: Please try not to [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954510/count-mismatches-between-rows-in-google-sheet). If you do so, please let us know that you already have a solution so one does not have to expect a respond form you. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross-posting across [se] is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry about that!!!! My big apologize.